# What are the different use cases in economics for the different definitions of unemployment published by the Bureau of Labor Statistics?

Tags: unemployment

The BLS releases the unemployment rate in the United States once every month. This unemployment rate (officially U-3) is defined as the total unemployed as a percentage of the the total civilian work force where unemployed people are those who are willing and available to work, and who have actively sought work within the past four weeks.

However, the BLS publishes 5 other unemployment statistics that measure different definitions of unemployment (U-1 to U-6). U-6 is often said to be the "true" unemployment rate as it includes people who are marginally attached to the labor force, plus those who are employed part-time for economic reasons.

That being said, what are the use cases in economics for the different unemployment measures? When would U-1, or U-5, or any of the others be used over any other definition?

Comment: Some people want to look at long-term unemployment (U1), others at people who lost jobs but not those new to the market (U2), and yet others at people who are not looking for work but might have worked (U4) or might work (U5), and finally at those in work who want to work more (U6)

Comment: Agree with @Henry’s remark. I am not sure that there can be an answer other than something like “economists choose a measure based on what they are interested in.” For example, underemployment is a concern in recent decades, and U-6 captures that better than U-3. (In terms of terminology, U-3 is the “headline rate”: the rate of unemployment used without qualification in the official press release, and used in headlines in the press.

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk If it really is that simple, I guess the question can be closed.